# Custom Engine With Compositor Services (Apple VisionOS)

Tags: swiftui, metal, realitykit, visionos

I want to draw my own content in fully immersive space in VisionOS. According to apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/compositorservices/drawing_fully_immersive_content_using_metal) it's possible through Metal, but I don't have much knowledge about Metal. Can any one please provide me how to create metal engine for drawing straight line.

Comment: You don't have to use Metal, you can still use any other SwiftUI view for an Immersive experience https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10113/